# Translate this proof from German to English

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems, translation-request

I need your help to translate some exercises from German to English. I will attach like images. Thanks :)

> **Satz 3.** Es sei $(X,d)$ ein ultrametrischer Raum. $X$ ist genau dann transvollständig, wenn jede kontrahierende Abbildung $A:X\to X$ einen (und dann auch genau einen) Fixpunkt in $X$ hat.
>
> **Beweis.** 1) Sei $X$ transvollständig und $A:X\to X$ eine kontrahierende Abbildung. Wir gewinnen einen Fixpunkt für $A$ mit einer ähnlichen Idee, wie man in einem Körper von formalen Potenzreihen zu einem Element das Inverse als Pseudolimes einer geeigneten Folge bestimmen kann (vgl. $[8]$, S. $51$, Satz $3$).
>
> Angenommen, $A$ hat keinen Fixpunkt in $X$. Dann ist $0\ne\Delta:=\{d(Ax,x):x\in X\}$. Die Menge $\Delta$ ist ohne kleinstes Element; denn ist $d(Ax,x)\in\Delta$, so erhält man mit $x':=Ax$, daß $d(Ax',x')\in\Delta$ und $d(Ax',x')=d(A(Ax),Ax)<d(Ax,x)$ ist. Es sei $\rho$ der Koinitialitätstyp von $\Delta$ und die Folge $(\pi_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ streng monoton fallend und koinitial in $\Delta$. Zu $\pi_\delta$ sei $x_\delta\in X$ mit $\pi_\delta=d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta)$ bestimmt. Wir zeigen, daß $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ pseudokonvergent ist: Sei dafür $\alpha<\beta<\rho$. Wegen $d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)\le\max\{d(x_\alpha,Ax_\alpha),d(Ax_\alpha,Ax_\beta),d(Ax_\beta,x_\beta)\}$ erhält man bei Berücksichtigung von $d(x_\alpha,Ax_\alpha)=\pi_\alpha>\pi_\beta=d(Ax_\beta,x_\beta)$ und $d(Ax_\alpha,Ax_\beta)<d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)$ mit $(\text{D}_3')$, daß $d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)=\pi_\alpha$ ist. Folglich ist $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ pseudokonvergent.
>
> Sei $x\in X$ ein Pseudolimes von $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$. Wegen $d(Ax,x)\in\Delta$ und der Koinitialität von $(\pi_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ in $\Delta$ gibt es ein $\delta<\rho$ mit $\pi_\delta<d(Ax,x)$. Es ist $$d(Ax,x)\le\max\{d(Ax,Ax_\delta),d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta),d(x_\delta,x)\}\;,$$ woraus wegen $d(Ax,Ax_\delta)<d(x,x_\delta)=\pi_\delta$ und $d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta)=\pi_\delta$ weiter $d(Ax,x)\le\pi_\delta$ folgt, was jedoch der Wahl von $\delta$, nämlich $\pi_\delta<d(Ax,x)$, widerspricht.
>
> Also ist $0\in\Delta$, und damit gibt es ein Element $x\in X$ mit $Ax=x$. Wäre auch $y\in X$ mit $y\ne x$ ein Fixpunkt von $A$, so wäre $d(Ax,Ay)=d(x,y)$, was wegen andererseits $d(Ax,Ay)<d(x,y)$ nicht möglich ist.
>
> 2) Sei nun vorausgesetzt, daß jede kontrahierende Abbildung von $X$ einen Fixpunkt in $X$ habe.
>
> Angenommen, $X$ ist nicht transvollständig. Dann gibt es eine pseudokonvergente Folge $(a_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$, $a_\delta\in X$, ohne Pseudolimes in $X$. Für $\pi_\delta:=d(a_\delta,a_{\delta+1})$ und $B_\delta:=B_{\pi_\delta}(a_\delta)$ gilt somit: $\bigcap_{\delta<\rho}B_\delta=\varnothing$. Wir definieren eine Abbildung $A:X\to X$. Zu $x\in X$ existiert eine kleinste Ordinalzahl $\delta<\rho$ mit $x\notin B_\delta$, es sei $Ax:=a_\delta$. Wegen $x\notin B_\delta$ und $Ax\in B_\delta$ ist $A$ ohne Fixpunkt in $X$. Wir zeigen, daß $A$ kontrahierend ist: Seien dafür $x,y\in X$ mit $x\ne y$, $Ax=a_\delta$, $\ldots$

Comment: chances are nobody will do this for you

Comment: Why would we do this for you?

Comment: Because I have to understand this proof for a new study

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Given that (translation-request) is a valid tag, and the paper in question is about mathematics, I fail to see why this off topic. I agree it is slightly ambitious, but questions like this have been answered before, and there have been a number of meta discussions showing support for such questions - see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions?lq=1 for example

Comment: @5xum why would we answer any question posted on this site if not to help people understand mathematics.

Comment: I think you have much better chance that somebody will answer you, if you retype the content. (If somebody volunteers to translate this, they can work faster if the mathematical parts are already LaTeX-ed.)

Comment: Try scanning  it on OCR. (optical cryptography recognition ) and post them both . It could  cut down somewhat on tedious work of google translation etc. editing & Latexing by someone inclined to help.

Comment: @Mathmo123: It’s not the Banach fixed point theorem: the setting is different, since the ultrametric $d$ may be taking values in a non-Archimedean ordered field.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks. As is evident, my German isn't great.

Comment: @5xum: Because the mathematics interests me, it’s helpful to someone, and I like to keep up my German. This is by no means the first time that I’ve responded to such requests.

Comment: The result in the post seems interesting. I would appreciate knowing what book does it come from.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As this question [was reopened](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1278723/revisions), I suggest that you should move your translation from the question to an answer. (Having an upvoted answer should prevent [auto-deletion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info), if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Theoretically, you could buy yourself a German-English dictionary and work your way through that proof. I think there's some mathematician who taught himself German that way.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the notification; done.

Answer (score 6):

In the translation below I’ve coined the term *trans-complete* to translate *transvollständig*; it apparently means that every transfinite sequence that is Cauchy in the generalized sense suitable to the (not necessarily real-valued) ultrametric is pseudo-convergent.

> **Theorem 3.** Let $(X,d)$ be an ultrametric space. $X$ is then trans-complete exactly when each contractive mapping $A:X\to X$ has one (and then exactly one) fixed point in $X$
>
> **Proof.** 1) Let $X$ be trans-complete and $A:X\to X$ a contractive mapping. We obtain a fixed point of $A$ with an idea similar to the way in which one can specify the inverse of an element in a field of formal power series as the pseudo-limit of a suitable sequence (cf. $[8]$, p. $51$, Theorem $3$).
>
> Suppose that $A$ has no fixed point in $X$. Then $0\notin\Delta:=\{d(Ax,x):x\in X\}$. The set $\Delta$ has no smallest element; for if $d(Ax,x)\in\Delta$, we can set $x'=Ax$ to get $d(Ax',x')\in\Delta$ and $d(Ax',x')=d(A(Ax),Ax)<d(Ax,x)$. Let $\rho$ be the co-initiality of $\Delta$, and let $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ be a strictly monotone decreasing sequence co-initial in $\Delta$. For each $\pi_\delta$ fix $x_\delta\in X$ with $\pi_\delta=d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta)$. We’ll show that $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ is pseudo-convergent.
>
> To this end let $\alpha<\beta<\rho$. Since $$d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)\le\max\{d(x_\alpha,Ax_\alpha),d(Ax_\alpha,Ax_\beta),d(Ax_\beta,x_\beta)\}\;,$$ $d(x_\alpha,Ax_\alpha)=\pi_\alpha>\pi_\beta=d(Ax_\beta,x_\beta)$, and $d(Ax_\alpha,Ax_\beta)<d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)$, we see that $d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)=\pi_\alpha$, and it follows that $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ is pseudo-convergent.
>
> Let $x\in X$ be a pseudo-limit of $(x_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$. Since $d(Ax,x)\in\Delta$, and $(\pi_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$ is co-initial in $\Delta$, there is a $\delta<\rho$ such that $\pi_\delta<d(Ax,x)$. We have
>
> $$d(Ax,x)\le\max\{d(Ax,Ax_\delta),d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta),d(x_\delta,x\}\;,$$
>
> and moreover $d(Ax,Ax_\delta)<d(x,x_\delta)=\pi_\delta$ and $d(Ax_\delta,x_\delta)=\pi_\delta$, so $d(Ax,x)\le\pi_\delta$, contradicting the choice of $\delta$.
>
> Thus, $0\in\Delta$, and there is therefore an element $x\in X$ such that $Ax=x$. If there were also a fixed point $y$ of $A$ in $X$ with $y\ne x$, we’d have $d(Ax,Ay)=d(x,y)$, which is impossible, since $d(Ax,Ay)<d(x,y)$.
>
> 2) Now assume that every contractive mapping on $X$ has a fixed point in $X$.
>
> Suppose that $X$ is not trans-complete. Then there is a pseudo-convergent sequence $(a_\delta)_{\delta<\rho}$, $a_\delta\in X$, without a pseudo-limit in $X$. If $\pi_\delta:=d(a_\delta,a_{\delta+1})$ and $B_\delta:=B_{\pi_\delta}(a_\delta)$, it follows that $\bigcap_{\delta<\rho}B_\delta=\varnothing$. We now define a mapping $A:X\to X$. For each $x\in X$ there is a smallest ordinal $\delta<\rho$ such that $x\notin B_\delta$, and we set $Ax:=a_\delta$. Then $x\notin B_\delta$ and $Ax\in B_\delta$, so $x$ is not a fixed point of $A$, and $A$ therefore has no fixed point in $X$. We now show that $A$ is contractive.
>
> To this end let $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$, $Ax=a_\delta$, $\ldots$